# Delete Single Student from Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I cannot get this function to work properly. It crashes when I try to delete a specific record. What do I need to change for it to work as expected?

```
//Delete Students Function
void delete_single_Student(Student *pfirst, int id)
{
    int search_id;
    bool found = false;

    Student *pcurrent = pfirst;
    Student *temp = NULL;


    printf("Please enter the student ID of the student that will be deleted.\n");
    scanf("%d", &search_id);

        while (search_id < 999 || search_id > 9999)
        {
            printf("\nPlease enter a valid id.\n");
            scanf("%d", &search_id);
        }
            do
            {
                temp = pcurrent;
                pcurrent = pcurrent->next;

                if (pfirst->id == search_id)
                {
                    found == true;
                    printf("**********************\n\n");
                    printf("    Student %d Deleted   \n\n", search_id);
                    printf("*********************\n\n");
                    pfirst = pfirst->next;
                    free(temp);
                    break;
                }

            } while (found != true);
}
```

Comment: what are you doing with `temp`? what' happens to the flag `found`?

Comment: What is `id` for?

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for user input.

Comment: You need to set `found=true` at some point in the code. But there's also the case where you don't find the `search_id` in the list. So the loop also has to terminate when you reach the end of the list.

Comment: Nothing about this code makes sense. There's no part that even tries to delete a record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you are querying pfirst, but you are not generally changing pfirst in your loop.  The conditional will only be true if the first element is your result.  Additionally, found != true is always true, so you are bound to end up with a pcurrent null pointer after traveling the list and upon referencing pcurrrent->next, you bomb.

I would suggest that you incrementally attack with easier problems.

1) Just write a procedure to print each element, terminating when the pointer is null.  You do not need a found variable.

2) Repeat number #1 but print that element side by side with its predecessor, requiring you to track the previous element.

3) After mastering #2, you will see that the first element is a special case and that you cannot really solve the problem without having access to the information that the calling function had.

Comment: This is what I am getting now-
Student ID      : 529424 (was 4444)
Name            :
First Name      :
Age             : 31